# Proper Flyback Current Protection Circuit for Variable Voltage Solenoid Driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, protection, solenoid, flyback, polarity

I am using a darlington buffered op-amp to drive a solenoid motor at variable voltages (for variable speeds of actuation). Here is my circuit as it is now:

[image: Solenoid Circuit]

I am wondering which of the two flyback diodes (from coil to GND and coil to VCC) are necessary to drain flyback current from the solenoid, or if perhaps a resistor across the solenoid is necessary.

The diode from the op-amp output to the coil is to prevent flyback from interacting with the op-amp output. This one I am certain is necessary from hands-on testing.

Normally I see this as a flyback circuit:

[image: Standard Flyback]

But this is notably different from my case, sense it works by connecting and disconnecting the solenoid from ground, whereas my circuit provides a variable voltage at the input. I am wondering what I need to change in the flyback protection setup to account for this difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need change anything from default flyback protection. It is used to protect circuit from huge voltage spike that is induced by the coil. Inductors don't like fast current changes, generally speaking:

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

So, when the coil switch occurs, voltage in midpoint goes up to huge value. In order to avoid that, you need to add a path, in which current will be suppressed (snubber). Diode to the left is doing all the job, and diode to the right is useless (as voltage in midpoint is negative).

However, your circuit will change speed in which magnetic field change vill occur, but not the maximum magnetic flux. I would recommend you to check current controled coil instead of voltage controled, as with that you could limit the actual strength of a field. Sample circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIVOw9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hmm... What do you mean by current controlled vs. voltage controlled? I'm using circuit I posted to achieve the result of variable velocity, so isn't that voltage control? And voltage is a result of current and vice versa anyway, so by changing voltage one changes current. I tried something like the circuit you posted with the solenoid on the transistor collector but could not get it to work.

Comment: Also, it's a positive charge that builds up on the input to the coil, so having a diode to ground seems like it would be the useless one, since only negative current can flow through that diode. I thought by having a diode to VCC this positive charge could drain. Why isn't this the case?

Comment: Also, I think it may actually be exactly that difference in speed with which the magnetic field changes that is producing variable velocities of firing. Which is the result I want, so that's a good thing, and not something I want to get rid of.

Comment: 1) In coil, voltage is a derivative of current, and current is integral of voltage, constant current leads to 0 voltage and constant voltage > 0 leads to increasing current
2) There is no "charge buildup" in coil, there is a "current buildup", diode to the left does all the job.
3) Force is proportional to magnetic flux that is proportional to current, not voltage

Comment: 2) Still doesn't really answer my question, which is about polarity. Just corrects my terminology. The current that builds up is positive, not negative. I've seen this on a scope. So wouldn't that positive current need to drain to VCC, not GND?

Comment: The voltage controls the rate of current rise which in turn controls the acceleration an rising velocity which in turn creates a back EMF that decreases the current and acceleration towards impact. So Voltage does control velocity but not in a linear mode as current feedback . Only a reverse power diode from emitter to Gnd is needed .

Comment: Yes, current in coil draws from input to GND, and coil tends to preserve its current, think of it as inductance is mass of an object, current is a speed of that object and voltage is force that you are putting on it. You are applying forward voltage, you get forward current, but when you try to stop the current it will still want to  move forward, so you put a diode (basicaly a soft wall near that object) to apply negative force and stop it, or else it will bump in something that you dont want to. So yes, you need to drain a positive current, but voltage is negative

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist When you say a diode from emitter to ground are you talking about the coil input to ground or the darlington emitter? Though I supposed they'd be the same when the diode from the op-amp output is removed.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist When I didn't have that diode between the op-amp and the emitter (with just the standard diode across the coil setup you are recommending) I had several op-amps burst into sulfuric flames. How do you explain that? I think hands on experience shows that it is necessary. Could it possibly be that the diode voltage drop is necessary so that the paths to ground and the op-amp output look the same to the flyback current?

Comment: Correct , only 1 power Schottky or Si diode emitter to gnd to clamp negative spike

Comment: Make sure the If on diode from solenoid current does not go below Vin absolute level-0.3 so add a series R of 100k or so  to Vin-